# mySQL - Grab top scores only from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql for grabbing the top scorers from a database;

```
SELECT name, score FROM arcade GROUP BY name ORDER BY score DESC
```

How can I only get each players highest score, rather than a random one?

(I know there is a similar post to this but that one has a lot of conditions that complexes it somewhat)

Comment: Simply select `max(score)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX()`?

```
select name, max(score)
from arcade
group by name;
```

Comment: I am dumb... I tried that but now realize what I did wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, 
       MAX(score) AS max_score
FROM arcade 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC;
```